# Im writing telegram bot in Python and want to create database if certain button is pressed. But Python can't see function which creates database

Tags: python

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'companies_list':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot.sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        users = cur.fetchall()

        info = ''
        for el in users:
            info += f'<b>Компания</b>: "{el[1]}"\n    <u>Культура</u>: <em>{el[2]}</em>\n'
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)

    if call.data == 'buy':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ознакомьтесь со списком компаний', reply_markup=companies_list)
    if call.data == 'sell':
        def test(message):
            conn2 = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot_table.sql')
            cur2 = conn2.cursor()

            cur2.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1 (id int auto_increment primary key, product varchar(50), price varchar(50))')
            conn2.commit()
            cur2.close()
            conn2.close()
....
```

So, first of all I added decorator for callback_data and in there im checking for data that's coming. If button that is responsible for data "sell" is pressed i create new data base as in the first time (code below). But it doesn't happen, python highlights in gray def test(message) and rejects creating DB.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Добро пожаловать, дорогой пользователь! Введите название вашей организации.')
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50), kultura varchar(50))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)
def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Теперь введите культуру, которой занимается ваша компания.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_kultura)
def user_kultura(message):
    kultura = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, kultura) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (name, kultura))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Компания успешно зарегистрирована!', reply_markup=companies_list)
```

Basically I tried to remove every def in if cal.data == "sell", and off it didn't work.

it says this

```
    product = call.text.strip()
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to access the `text` attribute of a `CallbackQuery` object, which doesn't exist. Callback queries don't have a `text` attribute; instead, they have `data`.

In the `callback` function, you're dealing with a callback query, so you should access the `data` attribute of the `call` object to determine which button was pressed.

Like this:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.data == 'companies_list':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot.sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        users = cur.fetchall()

        info = ''
        for el in users:
            info += f'<b>Компания</b>: "{el[1]}"\n    <u>Культура</u>: <em>{el[2]}</em>\n'
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)

    if call.data == 'buy':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ознакомьтесь со списком компаний', reply_markup=companies_list)
        
    if call.data == 'sell':
        # Define the function for selling
        def sell(message):
            product = message.text.strip()
            conn2 = sqlite3.connect('ETP_bot_table.sql')
            cur2 = conn2.cursor()

            cur2.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product VARCHAR(50), price VARCHAR(50))')
            conn2.commit()
            cur2.close()
            conn2.close()

        # Prompt the user to enter the product they want to sell
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Enter the product you want to sell:")
        # Register the next step handler to receive the product name
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, sell)
```